# Can the code in a .crx chrome app have write access to the files within itself (the crx)?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a crx that has a number of files that I want to be able to change over time. For example, it might have this structure:

```
index.html
js/code.js
images/someimage.png
```

I want to be able to use ajax (or JSONP) to download a new image and overwrite `image/someimage.png` (after the crx has been installed into chrome). Is this possible?

Comment: Vincent's answer is correct. The reason you can't do this is that we want users to be able to know what they're installing at installation time. Thus the installation prompt listing permissions, and the temporary disabling of apps/extensions when updating asks for more permissions. That's why the CRX needs to be static. (The argument is stronger for code than PNGs, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not modify the application / extension data files directly.

But, you can store a downloaded image to [chrome.storage](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/storage.html), [chrome.fileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/fileSystem.html), or [chrome.syncFileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/syncFileSystem.html). At run time you can check to see if a downloaded image is there and swap out your image reference. E.g. use a dataURL or blob.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was thinking but this could be tough with images referenced in CSS files. I'd have to separately keep track of those (e.g. background images) and update the class definitions when the images are changed. Is there any way to point a css style to a filesystem file?

Comment: You should be able to use a sandboxed filesystem (you don't need to use chrome.fileSystem for this, chrome.fileSystem is for files outside the sandbox). Sandboxed FileEntries have URLs which you should be able to point your css at dynamically.

Comment: @BenWells Can you add a link showing me how to get the URL from a sandboxed FIleEntry? I wasn't aware that was possible. And are you sure this is implemented in the latest Chrome?